# Variable replacement in tables with two loops

Tags: matlab, loops, indexing

I wish to change variable names in a loop. The name is written in some cell array, like here:

[image: http://imgur.com/szqGzkH]

```
ML.species1{1:end,end+1}=0;
i=1:height(ML.species1);
        ML.species1{i,end}=(ML.species1.someindex(i)*3+(ML.species1.someotherindex(i)
end
```

I can't just call the name of the variable and say `ML.(ML.speciesname{1,1}){i,end}=`... why not?

and if that should work, id like to make a second loop around the basic calculation, just exchanging the variables here `ML.speciesname{1,j}` one by one by moving my index `j` to column name 2, 3 ... How does that work?

Comment: Trying to understand - you want to call a variable by a different name? How is that name obtained? From a string somewhere? In what scope do you want to do this? Is it enough to call a function with a local variable with a different name? Sorry - I think you need to be more specific about what you are trying to do - and why.

Comment: thank you very much for asking this. yes i want to call a variable which looks like this

ML.species1=...
rather ML.species2=...

but i want to reference myself on some name which is written down in a string. 

then i wish to calculate stuff with this different variable and store the result somewhere else than the first calculation calculated with the first variable. and then i wish to jump to the next variable which is again in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still not 100% sure what you are trying to do - but I believe the following should help:

You can access an element in a structure in different ways:

```
ML.element1='hello world';
fieldName = 'element1';
disp(getfield(ML, fieldName));
```

As you can see, using `getfield` I can access an element even if I don't know the name of the element at the time I write the code (as long as I have the name in a variable).

Similarly, you can use `setfield` to create an element:

```
setfield(ML, fieldName, 'goodbye world');
disp(ML.element1);
```

**update** - if you want to *index* an element of a specific (variable) field name, you could do the following:

```
fieldname = 'one';
ML.(fieldname) = [123 234];
ML.(fieldname)(3) = 456;
disp(ML)

ML = 

  one: [123 234 456]
```

Note - the trick is in the `()` parentheses around the (variable) name of the field.

Comment: although i get your example i do not quite see how to call a dynamic fieldname, how would you do that in a calculation which needs to index into different rows?

Comment: maybe let me rephrase my question, how do you index a specific fieldname?

Comment: it took me some time but it was really just the parenthesis thing. many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might find the `eval` function useful for using strings to define variable names and values. For example if you have a name you want to give a variable in `strVarName` (a string) and a value for it in `dValue` (a double), you can write:

```
eval([strVarName ' = ' num2str(dValue) ';']);
```

[Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) for `eval`.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what the OP is after; I did toy with the thought of using eval, but since it seems he's after elements of a structure I am not sure this will work. But it is definitely a useful function for this general type of problem. I'm upvoting because you included a link to the documentation.

Comment: I actually like your answer better because I was unaware of `getfield` and have been using `eval` to do a lot of name-based parsing. This will definitely come in handy.

Comment: thank you for eval but i think its more this getfield i should be able to use. i found more information about generating field names from variables but i think i dont see the forest from the trees

http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html